# ModuleNotFound Error with VSCode Python 3.8.2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a greenhorn, so go easy on me:

I've been trying to divide up a python project I was working on into smaller parts. To that end I created 4 Classes inside a single folder in VSCode, one being a main class that imports the other 3 and accesses their methods etc.

The structure is as following:

```
top_level_folder
|--lower_level_folder
 |--class1.py
 |--class2.py
 |--class3.py
 |--mainclass.py
```

Now my mainclass is supposed to import the other 3 classes, via

```
from top_level_folder.lower_level_folder import class1
etc.
```

However, doing it this way, I get a ModuleNotFound Error (no module named top_level_folder)

```
import class1
etc
```

results in a TypeError
and

```
import top_level_folder.lower_level_folder.class1 as x
```

doesn't work either

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Is it down to my VSC installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you're running mainclass.py as your executable script, your import should look like this
**mainclass.py**

```py
from class1 import MyClass
```

But if you're planning on importing the module from outside the folder, you'll either need an `__init__.py` file, or you would specify the folder name. I.e your file structure looks like this

```
top_level_folder
|--lower_level_folder
 |--__init__.py
 |--class1.py
 |--class2.py
 |--class3.py
 |--mainclass.py
|--main.py
```

your would import like this
**main.py**

```py
from mainclass import MyClass
```

**mainclass.py**

```py
from lower_level_folder.class1 import MyClass2
```

**__init__.py**

```py
from lower_level_folder.mainclass import MyClass
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I am indeed running mainclass.py as my executable.