# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'src'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module-export

I am facing this problem while my "from src.simulation.simulator import Simulator" is in the same directory. what should i do now to resolve this problem?

I have tried to solve this problem but did not understand what to do!!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your folder structure/packages ? Python import are notably difficult to use for a beguinner for custom packages. I encourage to read this source :https://realpython.com/python-import/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61575987/18359438) solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't updated for a long time, I have made a guess.

This maybe caused by vscode using workspace as root floder.

This will lead to a problem. When you use the `os.getcwd()` method in the deep directory of the workspace, you will still get the workspace directory.

You can open your settings and search **Python > Terminal: Execute In File Dir** then check it.

[image]

You can also use debug mode and add the following to your **launch.json**:

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```